# how will google/gtm-oauth2 / GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch work in April?

Tags: ios, google-oauth

i am using gtm-oauth2 (as part of https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client ) and I started getting a warning about webviews not being supported to sign in on april 2017.

i assume they want me to move to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/ , but I can't find an example how to integrate the sign-in sdk with https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest or https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client which seem to still want to handle sign in with GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch which as I understand is not acceptable under the new rules

my question: what mix of google sdks allows me to sign in to google the correct way and then access things like google drive apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is I should be using https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth 
and not https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Comment: ...with the grand question being: How exactly, especially in Swift?

Comment: any updates? I am stuck at this. need help with swift implementation.